# Is it possible to use ShowBalloonTip on a notifyicon without playin a sound?

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

I'm using notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(30000); to display some status change but it also plays a defaul windows sound, is it possible to no play the sound?

Comment: Thats the user's choice.  They are in charge of their system.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Sorry forgot to add winforms

Comment: Windows 10 changed the default.  Just change it back the way you want it, Control Panel > Sounds.  Do consider that if your own program annoys you then you might be annoying the user with balloons too often.  Those balloons are also *very* easy to disable in Win10 so the user can easily do something about it :)

Comment: @HansPassant Actually under Windows 10, I just saw that the user can choose to disable the sound of notifications **per application**.